# Insert URL into jQuery return <button>

Tags: jquery, wordpress

See image for details:

[image: http://oi48.tinypic.com/564x4.jpg]

```
base.prototype.pre_edit_button = function() {
      var _this = this;
      return jQuery('<button>', {
        'class': 'fee-hover-edit',
        'html': FrontEndEditor.data.edit_text,
        'click': function(ev) {
          _this.last_mouse_pos = ev.pageY;
          return _this.start_editing();
        }
      });
```

Url to be redirected (back-end page edit): **wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=page**

My lame try:

```
    }, base.prototype.edit_button = function () {
        var _this = this;
        return jQuery("<?php edit_post_link( __( 'Full Edit',) ?> ", {
        })
```

I know nothing of PHP/jQuery/Javascript, it didn't show up anything, but at least script kept running

Notes:

`edit_post_link` is a wordpress function that redirects to the full-editing of the current page. I won't use it, I'll just try to redirect to that url mentioned above.

Comment: What files are the above code located in?

Comment: @Fresheyeball, **front-end-editor/build/editor-min.js**: http://pastebin.com/JYfX9PrD <br/> Front-end-editor plugin:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/front-end-editor/